# How do I initialize the month in bootstrap calendar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, calendar

Simple question. I have a series of bootstrap calendars at this site here:

http://hollandandbarnes.azurewebsites.net/entertainment/upcoming-events/

I want to know how I can set the initial month of the calendar. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set year and month like this

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
        //..
        defaultViewDate: {
            year: 2020, //can be omitted.
            month: 10-1 //starts at 0, so subtract 1 to reach actual month like 10 -1 for October or use index from 0, 0 = Jan and so on..
        }
    });
```

**Example: Run code snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        //..
        defaultViewDate: {
            year: 2020,
            month: 10-1
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" />
Click the field
<input type="text" id="datepicker" />
```

Comment: Hmm... I see your example works, but for some reason it isn't working for me. I've updated the link above to use your approach. I'm using bootstrap 3.3.7. Is it possible that defaultViewDate is newer than that?

Comment: @gib65 What do you mean by "Is it possible that defaultViewDate is newer than that?"

Comment: I mean that if I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.7, maybe defaultViewDate doesn't exist in my version. So maybe it was introduced in a later (newer) version. Do you know where I can find documentation for specific versions?

Comment: @gib65 I have included bootstrap 3.3.7 and you can see it is still working alright. There may be something else which is creating issue on your website, may be compatibility issue with other libraries

Answer (score 0):

Ambrish's answer may work with the latest version of Bootstrap, but with version 3.3.7, I found this to work:

```
const d = new Date();
d.setMonth(desiredMonth); // where desiredMonth is a number between 0 and 11
$('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', d);
```